# Related terms summary views block

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type with two fields for two different taxonomy vocabularies (Section & Extras). "Section" only have one value, while "Extras" can have multiple values.

I created a block using Views for the "Section" term page that will list in a summary display the "Extras" terms the node tagged with "Section" have using the term page argument.

The issue I am having is that in the view I had to use two arguments and the two arguments are part of the summary base path and I just want to use the second one:

**Right now my URLs look like:**

/taxonomy/term/X/Y (where X is the tid of "Section" and Y the tid of "Extras")

**I want it look like:**

/taxonomy/term/Y (where Y is the tid of "Extras")

**Current arguments or contextual filters:**

1. The "Section" field getting the Taxonomy term from the URL
2. The (relationship to "Terms on node")Taxonomy:Term id to create the summary display

I have tried a combination of %2, !2, 2%, 2!, %taxonomy_term, [tid], etc without any luck.

**Note:** the results of the views are perfect, it is just the URL been overwritten by the summary display.